# How can I disable cache for http headers?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, cookies, http-headers

I am reading about [HTTP basic authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basic_access_authentication).  On the MDN website, it says:

> Because BA header has to be sent with each HTTP request, the web browser needs to cache the credentials for a reasonable period to avoid constant prompting user for the username and password. Caching policy differs between browsers. Microsoft Internet Explorer by default caches them for 15 minutes.

However, **after I told the [chrome postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/settings) to send a request without a cached header** I still noticed the presence of an `authorization` field when I logged traffic at the server side:

```
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  authorization: 'Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=',   // why?
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'postman-token': '7e458c2d-b11b-026d-809b-68a7cf3d5a37',
  ....
```

Then I also tried using just **google chrome**, but I again saw an `authorization` field:

```
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  authorization: 'Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=', // again
  ....
```

Question 1: I disabled cache for both **Chrome** (I couldn't find the **no-cached option**, so I just selected **"disable cache"** in the chrome debugger) and **postman** (which has an option for "no-cached header"), but they still included the `authentication` header...why?  How can I prevent them from doing this?

Question 2: Same thing happened when I tried to make the client **not** to send back the **Cookie**, I even use the *clear cookie* functionality in chrome history... but I still see its presence in request header. I assume each header field is cached differently, so how can I manage the cookies?

**Opening an incognito window will make the browser forget about the authorization and cookie... but only once: subsequent tabs will have these headers.**

Comment: I just learnt that these cookies are called browser session cookies, they will go away if I close and reopen the browser (or open an icognito), but do I have no other means of controlling them?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing, it's frustrating. But you can click the 'Disable Cache' option in the Chrome Network inspector and it will/should remove it (In my case I just needed it to update the cache with a new Auth header).

This is concerning though because if a user logs into an app and the token expires, the app could refresh it and serve the new token to the http client, but Chrome will automatically overwrite it with the expired token...

Comment: The OP already mentioned using this feature, but claims to still receive the error.